# UPDATE deeply nested jsonb array structure in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a simple table with a structure as follows:

```
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | data (jsonb)                                                                             |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | {a: 1, b: [{id: 10, name: "Ton"}, {id: 20, name: "Maria"}, {id: 30, name: "Jack"}]       |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2  | {a: 2, b: [{id: 40, name: "Hello!"}, {id: 50, name: "Peter"}, {id: 60, name: "Wilson"}]} |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 3  | {a: 3, b: [{id: 10, name: "Ton"}, {id: 70, name: "Joana"}, {id: 80, name: "Ana"}]}       |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you look closely at rows `1` and `3`, I have two listings inside the `data.b` array with the same `id` and `name`:

```
{id: 10, name: "Ton"}
```

How can I update both nested ocurrences of "Ton" (`id: 10`) with PostgreSQL?

For example, if "Ton" was a typo and now needs to be updated to "Tom", my query logic would be:

```
 1. Find all "data.b" occurrences where id = 10 (Ton)
 2. If any was found, update "data.b[index].name" to "Tom"
```

I managed to update a single occurrence by manually using [`jsonb_set()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html) and passing the index of the occurrences, but how can I make work with an array of indefinite occurrences?

```sql
-- Works well updating a single occurrence in a single index.
-- How write this to update all occurrences in the jsonb array?
UPDATE my_table SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{b,0,name}', 'Tom') WHERE layout_news::json#>>'{b,0,id}' = '10'
```

Is it something possible to do with PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes they are called tables. Postgres is a SQL database, make use of those features and save yourself these problems.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver This particular case would lead to numerous new tables, relations and complexity, which could lead to performance issues and unnecessary complexity.